# How do lexers treat overlapping terminals?

Tags: parsing, lex, lexical-analysis, regular-language

From what I understand:

- Lexers tokenize text by a set of terminals.
- Terminals are regular expressions.

I'm about to implement a lexer for a simple parser generator I'm working on. I would build the lexer this way:

1. There is a set of terminals
2. All these terminals are combined into a NFA (remembering the final state of each terminal)
3. This NFA is then converted into a DFA (mapping the final state of each terminal)

Then if the lexer was about to lex a token, the implementation would:

1. Try the combined DFA on the next symbols until it fails
2. Find the last final state it entered
3. Map that state to the predefined terminal

(and feed terminal including the matched string to the parser).

---

The problem arises with this approach when there are at least two terminals defined where the languages intersect. Consider the following terminals:

```
Name = [a-z0-9]+
Number = [0-9]+
```

So language of `number` is actually a sublanguage of `name`.

If the lexer was about to analyze the string `123`, the next token can either be a name **or** a number.

What is wrong with my design? Or is it needed to feed the parser multiple possible terminals?

Comment: The first rule to match gets the token.  If there is a *conflict* between the rules, the lexer will generate an error.  Either way, there's no ambiguity.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [literals extraction policy for a lexical Analyzer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40242147/literals-extraction-policy-for-a-lexical-analyzer)